# Java Hamcrest Matcher check if list contains another list

Tags: java, assertion, hamcrest

I want to compare if a list is a sublist of another list

Assume I have the following lists

```
List<String> checkList = Arrays.asList("a", "d");

List<String> actualList = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d");
```

I want to check if `actualList` contains `checkList` . I can iterate each value and compare. But is there any hamcrest matcher that will do the job

For ex.

`a`,`d` should pass

`a`,`b`,`c` should pass

But `a`,`e` should fail

the `hasItems` supports the strings to be passed individually, and `contains` is checking for all the values, `in` supports an item to be present in a list. But I wanted

`assertThat(actualList,containsList(checkList))`

Is there any inbuilt matcher available or do I need to write custom matcher?

Comment: Have a look at [`IsIterableContainingInOrder<E>`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/collection/IsIterableContainingInOrder.html), maybe that's what you need. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15609132/how-to-check-if-collection-contains-items-in-given-order-using-hamcrest) is relevant, too.

Comment: @deHaar that will evaluate only one item. not list

Comment: OK, maybe you have to write your own `Matcher`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34589894/hamcrest-matcher-for-a-sublist-partial-match).

Comment: `hasItems` should work. Just convert your list to an array. `checkList.toArray(new String[0])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`hasItems` accepts a varargs parameter, so you can just convert your list to an array and pass it (alternatively, just declare it as an array to begin with):

```
final List<String> checkList = Arrays.asList("a", "d");
// final String[] checkListAsArray = new String[] { "a", "d" };
final String[] checkListAsArray = checkList.toArray(new String[checkList.size()]);
final List<String> actualList = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d");
assertThat(actualList, Matchers.hasItems(checkListAsArray));
```

The order of the checkList is not important.

If you swap the roles of `checkList` and `actualList`, you could also write:

```
assertThat(checkList, everyItem(isIn(actualList)));
```

This is probably more readable than:

```
assertTrue(actualList.stream().allMatch(checkList::contains));
```

Comment: +1 for `assertThat(checkList, everyItem(isIn(actualList)))`. In particular, the output of this on failure is much more readable than just asserting equality of two lists, or the `assertTrue` option. And it's a lot fewer lines than converting to an array :)

Comment: `isIn` is deprecated in the newer versions, but `is(in(...))` can be used instead or simply `in(...)`